# Excel string comparisons with escape character, using boolean, match or sumif

Tags: excel, string, comparison, excel-2016

When I was handeling a text-comparison in my database I noticed some odd behavior. In my database I want to SUM values based on a column containing strings. In this example, I want to make a group `str` and a group `txt`, with the following string values.

```
str     2
str1    1
str2    0
txt     1
txt1    2
tx2     3
```

If I would compare the text with a simpel boolean, i.e. =("str"="str*"), it returns `False`, because the `*` is an additional character. This makes sense in some way. However, when I used two other techniques the comparison is handled differently:

First, the following simple SUMIFS function:
`=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"str*")` and `=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"txt*")` includes the values at "str" and "txt" respectively, suggesting the comparison is `True`.

Second, `=Match("str*";{Cell containing "str"};0)` returns 1, indicating that the comparison also returns `True`.

**Why does the boolean string comparison return `False`, whilst `MATCH` and `SUMIFS` assume `True`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion those two functions apply the wildcard interpretation of the asterisks while your direct comparison formula with '=' takes it as just another (extra) character in the string inside the quotes, so making the two strings different.

While in the function Match():
If match_type is 0 and lookup_value is text, lookup_value can contain the wildcard characters asterisk (*) and question mark (?). An asterisk matches any sequence of characters; a question mark matches any single character.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Only a limited number of Excel worksheet functions can use wildcard characters to filter results. Functions like `COUNTIF` ,`VLOOKUP`, `MATCH` and others as listed [here](http://www.exceluser.com/excel_help/functions/guide-to-excel-wildcards.htm) are some Excel functions that use wildcards.

Apart from the functions listed in the link, wildcard `*` is treated like a literal when used in the double quotes.